# Error starting cygwin sshd on Windows 8

Tags: cygwin, windows-8, windows-8.1, cygwin-sshd

After installing sshd via cygwin on Windows 8 on a system that is not on a domain, the service will not start but gives an error such as:
Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start.

Looking at the service it shows no dependencies. (Though I have seen people talking about Netlogon being related)

Answer (score 1):

Go to services (windows key-> search for services, or open control panel and search for services in the search box in the top right hand corner)
Find "Cygwin-sshd" in the list of services. Double click on the service and chose the "Logon" tab.
In the box next to "This account" you will see something like the following:
hostname/cyg_server
where hostname is your computer's name and cyg_server is the user created to start the service.

Replace the name of computer with a dot (.) so it looks like this:
 ./cyg_server

Click ok and then try to start the service.

Hat tip to Konsto in the comments at this page for finding this: http://izadpanah.blogspot.com/2010/01/cygwin-sshd-service-not-starting-on.html

(I realize I'm answering my own question, but this was very annoying and I wanted to put it somewhere so others could find it.)